# JQuery Dialog no close when clicked outside

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have the following code, but when I click outside the dialog is not closed. any help? When I press the escape key closes the dialog

```
var iframe = $('<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMypagetest&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80&amp;appId=15226544646" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
var dialog = $("<div><br></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
    title: 'Danos un me gusta!',
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 150
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 150
    },
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    open: function() {
        jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
        })
    }
});
$('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TRY THE FOLLOWING CODE

```
$("body").not('#dialog').click( function(e) {
    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I think it may be because there is no div "dialog"

Comment: The HTML es very simple, only has a head and body